# Android TCP Client Incorrect

Tags: java, android, tcp, client

"I have a simple client running and it connects to my server; however, after connecting i cant receive back any data. I'm guessing something needs to be put into a while loop so the thread doesnt finish but i dont know what to put in it. Can someone help me out or give me a clue please?

```
  Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                 try {
                      socket = new Socket("255.255.255.255", 9999);
                      dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                      dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                      dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Send this text to the server");
                      Log.i("Appname", dataInputStream.readUTF());

                     } catch (someexceptionhere) {

                     }

            } 
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrapped the way I was receiving and i'm using:

```
socket.getInputStream().read(incomingdata);
```

Seems to work now thx

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to flush your streams if they are not set to autoflush.

```
Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      socket = new Socket("255.255.255.255", 9999);
      dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Send this text to the server");
      dataOutputStream.flush();
      Log.i("Appname", dataInputStream.readUTF());
    } catch (Exception _) {}
}
```

Comment: Didn't work =(
I can receive one message directly after I send the initial one to the server, but only if I immediately echo a message back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The thread is killed when its `run()` method returns or all pointers to it are cleared. You should use a while loop to keep your code running, but make sure you use `Thread.sleep()` in the loop to keep your thread from overloading the device. 10ms or more should work, but don't set it to any less than you need.